# How to completely remove "certbot" from ubuntu?

Tags: letsencrypt

I've tried

```
sudo apt-get remove python-certbot-apache
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove python-certbot-apache
sudo apt-get remove  python3-certbot-apache
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove python3-certbot-apache
```

but when I run command `certbot` it still is recognized. How can I completely remove it, thus, typing that command was like any unrecoginzed command.

Comment: While there is an accepted answer, I'm not sure the accepted answer is a full answer to this question. To fully remove certbot, do we want to make any changes to /etc/letsencrypt files, which reference certbot? I'm now switching a server from certbot to acme.sh. I know we go through the acme API for both to save letsencrypt data, but I'm not sure what files are certbot-specific in that process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do a search with:

```
sudo dpkg -l *certbot*
```

`-l *certbot*` does a regex search, so packages with names that include "certbot" will be returned in the search results.

```
dpkg-query -l *certbot*
```

will also do the same. From `man dpkg`:

```
dpkg-query actions
       See dpkg-query(1) for more information about the following actions.

       -l, --list package-name-pattern...
           List packages matching given pattern.
```

Also see `info dpkg`!

Comment: `sudo dpkg -l *certbot*` NO. --->   `sudo dpkg -l "*certbot*"` Yes. (Use double-quotes) You can run into problems without quotes. It may work - it may not.

Answer (score 30):

Below steps worked for me when I needed the same solution.

1. Remove Certbot

   ```
    sudo certbot delete
   ```
2. Remove Certbot's Apache package

   ```
    sudo apt purge python-certbot-apache
   ```
3. Disable the SSL config file created by certbot

   ```
    sudo a2dissite 000-default-le-ssl.conf
   ```
4. Remove certbot files manually

   ```
    sudo rm -rf /etc/letsencrypt/
    sudo rm -rf /var/lib/letsencrypt/
    sudo rm -rf /var/log/letsencrypt/
   ```
5. Make sure the repo is updated and autoremoved

   ```
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt upgrade
    sudo apt autoremove
   ```
6. **Cautious:** Additionally you can also reinstall apache2 if needed for fresh config files

   ```
    sudo apt purge apache2
    sudo apt install apache2
   ```

If `mods-available` folder also completely get purged during apache2 removal process then PHP will not be executed and code will be displayed on the browser. In my case, PHP version is 7.2 and executed the below. Adjust the below commands based on your PHP version.

```
    sudo apt purge libapache2-mod-php7.2
    sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.2
    sudo a2enmod php7.2
    sudo apachectl configtest
    sudo service apache2 restart
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 16):

If you have installed `certbot` using `snap`, this will work perfectly:

```sh
sudo snap remove certbot
```

Answer (score 6):

I tried to use `sudo apt install certbot` on my Ubuntu.
And it turns out the version `0.40.0` is far behind the current version `1.16`.

So I followed 5th step of the official instructions [here](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntufocal-other).

Run `sudo apt-get remove certbot` and `sudo apt autoremove`. It works for me.